# Not updating session properties in .onDefault

Tags: node.js, botframework

I've a code which is displayed below and the problem is that the userFailedC prop isn't getting incremented. I can set property but its value resets each time user's intent is not matched, i.e. each time .onDefault is executed.
Am I doing something wrong?
Also, I tried with userData and privateConversationData so I would bet that I misunderstood something.
Thank you!

```
bot.dialog('/', new builder.IntentDialog()
 .matches(/(hi|hello|hey)/i, function(session, args, next) {
   session.send(rm.get('Hi!');
   session.beginDialog('/showMainMenu');
 })
 .onDefault(function(session, args, next) {
   if ( session.dialogData.userFailedC === undefined ) {
     session.dialogData.userFailedC = 1;
   } else {
    session.dialogData.userFailedC++;
   }

   if (session.dialogData.userFailedC % 2 == 0) {
     session.send('Please say hi to me!');
   }
 })
 .onBegin(function(session, args, next) {
   next();
 })
);
```

Comment: I believe that it's not being saved because you're not calling next() or ending your onDefault dialog. session.endDialog()

Comment: Also, you will want to user userData, not dialogData for this. userData is maintained across dialogs, with your code's current setup userFailedC will always be set to 1.

Comment: Thanks @StevenG. that was it! Post it as an answer if you want, and I'll mark it as the right one

Comment: Great! I'm glad it works for you :) I've added an answer to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session data isn't being saved because the code is missing a `next()` or `session.endDialog()`. There are another methods that also save the session data, but these are the ones you're most likely to use when either moving through waterfall steps or switching/ending dialogs.

```
.onDefault(function(session, args, next) {
  if ( session.dialogData.userFailedC === undefined ) {
    session.dialogData.userFailedC = 1;
  } else {
    session.dialogData.userFailedC++;
  }

  if (session.dialogData.userFailedC % 2 == 0) {
    session.send('Please say hi to me!');
    // next() or session.endDialog()
  }
  // next() or session.endDialog()
})
```

In regards to storing `session.dialogData.userFailedC`, you'll want to use either `session.userData.userFailedC` or `session.conversationData.userFailedC` etc, as this will keep persist the data after the dialog has ended.